# How to select rows of a numpy data array according to class labels in a separate numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays a which has 2D vectors and class labels in a separate array.

```
a = np.random.random_sample((10000,2))
labels = [0]*10000
```

I use them like this

```
plot_data(a,np.matrix(np.asarray(labels)))
```

Now there are three classes 1 ,2  and 3 and I intend to extract the rows from 'a' vector corresponding to each class and plot it. 
I am not able to accomplish it. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
indices_0 = [k for k in range(0, X.shape[0]) if np.all(y == 1)]
indices_1 = [k for k in range(0, X.shape[0]) if np.all(y == 2)]
indices_2 = [k for k in range(0, X.shape[0]) if np.all(y == 3)]
```

How to select the rows(something like FIND in matlab)?

Comment: The standard Numpy way to get the indices where your labels are equal to `0` for example would be `np.where(labels == 0)[0]`. You need the `[0]` at the end because 'np.where' returns a tuple in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a NumPy's `nonzero` method.

Try doing so with:

```
indices_0 = a[np.nonzero(labels == 0)]
indices_1 = a[np.nonzero(labels == 1)]
indices_2 = a[np.nonzero(labels == 2)]
```

---

Explanation:

- `labels == 0` returns an array of `True` and `False` for every element of the vector `labels` that has a specified value,
- `np.nonzero(...)` returns a list of indices, for which vector had `True` values,
- `indices[...]` returns rows of the `indices` matrix filtered by the indices you provided with `nonzero`.

---

BTW: I recommend this cheatsheet for Matlab users: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html